# My bootloader can't read from Floppy (.flp) file in a Virtual Machine with this code?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bare-metal

Supposedly, this is correct (checked the usage of int 13h/AH=2 [here](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0607.htm))
and the bootloader is not made by me, but I read over the code multiple times and have attempted running it with different register values as well in hopes that maybe I was targeting the wrong drive or something simple like that, but to no avail. boot.bin and kernel.bin are both properly stored in os.flp, and were done so by the following in command prompt:

```
del os.flp
nasm boot.asm -f bin -o boot.bin
nasm kernel.asm -f bin -o kernel.bin
dd if=boot.bin of=os.flp bs=512 count=1
dd if=kernel.bin of=os.flp bs=512 count=1 seek=1
```

I'm using VMWare Workstation 12 Player to test it, and I'm booting it with os.flp in the Floppy Disk slot (Which I tested does load properly)

Here is the original bootloader.asm:

```
BITS 16
ORG 0x7C00

mov     dl, 2h ; drive 0 = floppy 1
mov     dh, 0h ; head (0=base)
mov     ch, 0h ; track/cylinder
mov     cl, 2h ; sector (1=bootloader)
mov     bx, 1000h ; place kernel in RAM @1000h
mov     es, bx ; place BX into pointer ES
mov     bx, 0h ; back to zero - also RAM-pos related

ReadFloppy:
mov     ah, 2h
mov     al, 1h
int 13h
jc  ReadFloppy ; if failed, loop

;pointers to RAM-pos
mov       ax, 1000h
mov       ds, ax
mov       es, ax
mov       fs, ax
mov       gs, ax
mov       ss, ax

jmp     1000h

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0AA55h ; magic number
```

This supposedly should load kernel.bin into memory and run it, which it doesn't. I checked for errors in my kernel.asm, but there don't seem to be any. However, just in case you need to see it,

Here is the kernel.asm as of now:

```
;set prnt-regs
mov     ah, 0Eh ; func nr
mov     bh, 0h ; page
mov     bl, 7h ; color

msg     db 'Hello, world from the kernel!', 13, 10, 0

mov     si, msg
call    prntstr
jmp     $ ;hang

prntstr:
.next_char:
mov     al, [si] ; current char
or      al, al
jz      .exit_char ; if current char = 0, go to end
int     10h ; prntchar
inc     si ; next char
jmp     .next_char
.exit_char:
ret

times 512 - ($ - $$) db 0
```

Any ideas on what's preventing it from loading it into memory?

Comment: Don't change the value in DL. The BIOS will pass in the correct value for the drive that it loaded the boot sector from. For a floppy drive that's normally 0 not 2.

Comment: Just a quick look: That's a string in the way of you code. `cs:1000h` is not `1000h:0000h`, the jump won't work. Maybe you should also set the stack pointer to be sure. Also divide et impera: write a very simple kernel that just print a char or, if you can check the registers, do a `cli/hlt`.

Comment: `mov     bx, 1000h ; place kernel in RAM @1000h` `mov     es, bx ; place BX into pointer ES` `mov     bx, 0h ; back to zero - also RAM-pos related
` for the _int 13h_ read is not doing what you think. ES is a segment and the read expects the address to read to, to be in _ES:BX_. You set _ES_ to 0x1000 and _BX_ to 0x0000. That is an address of 0x1000:0x0000 .The physical address that converts to is ((segment<<4)+offset) = (0x1000<<4)+0x0000=0x10000 (note: that is physical address 0x10000 and not 0x1000). Your code comment suggests you want to read to phys address 1000h but you are using 10000h

Comment: A good tutorial on how segmented addressing works in 16-bit real mode can be found here: http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html

Comment: If you did intend to load to physical address 10000h then as margaret points out you will have to modify your jump accordingly. Maybe `jmp 1000h:0000h`. That far jmp will set CS to 1000h and set IP = 0000h.

Comment: Success! Thanks, worked perfectly.